# How to show the preview window for vim omnicompletion under the current window?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make it open under the current active window instead of over it?
The standard setting always moves the whole content you are trying to look at down, including the selection window, which is kind of counterproductive.

Comment: You'd have to ask on SO to clear the migration history, but in essence, we have 1,530 vim questions here and they're on topic as well, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: There needs to be a clear rule, some questions are here, other questions there, some get migrated, others not…

Comment: They're on topic on both sites – choose whichever you want to post on.  Of course it shouldn't have been migrated in the first place if the MSO question you linked to still applies, but AFAICT there's a general shift towards closing anything not about *actual* programming problems on Stack Overflow, so the "tools used by programmers" is getting less important. Maybe raise it on [metase] to get consensus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set splitbelow
```

will deal with the issue.

You can add

```
set splitright
```

for good measure.

Comment: So there is no specific variable for the preview window?

Comment: Ah, and it still moves my main window. :(

Comment: You can set its height with `set previewheight` but nothing more specific. The preview window doesn't really "move" your main window: it reduces its height but the cursorline stays where it is which is the most important, IMO.